# CRUD for Live Objects FIFO?

Tags: crud, fifo, orange-api

I use Live Objects Fifo which are very useful for my application. To manage them i use the Portal for now, but I would need to manage them programmatically. Do you now if there is CRUD API for that ?
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can :)

Did you check the swagger ?

I think you can do that 
https://liveobjects.orange-business.com/swagger-ui/index.html#/Bus_management

and

https://liveobjects.orange-business.com/swagger-ui/index.html#/Bus_management_router